# How do I change the X-Range without altering the data in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

How do I change the xrange without affecting how my data on the plot looks? The range is `[0:1000]` and I want to switch it to `[0:100]`, what i actually want is to convert it instead of changing it by divinding the range by ten. But whenever I try, the way the plot looks also changes. I tried by using `xrange [0:100]` but it didn't work. Can someone help?

Comment: Please always add some minimal example data, code and graph to your question. So, what I understand you have data in the range of 0 to 1000 and want to divide the data by 10?

Comment: plot "residue.dat" with line and kind of yes, but i want the table to look the same. when i use xrange it only take the data between 0-100. but i want x to be in the interval of 0-100 with the table looking the same not altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without example data and graph it's still not fully clear to me, but my guess is the following: You want to divide your data by factor of 10. Check the following example.

**Code:**

```
### scale x-data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
   0   1
 100   2
 200   3
 300   4
 400   3
 500   2
 600   1
 700   2
 800   3
 900   4
1000   3
EOD

set key top center
set multiplot layout 2,1

    plot $Data u 1:2       w lp pt 7 lc "red"

    plot $Data u ($1/10):2 w lp pt 7 lc "web-green"

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked.